# Metric to check the number of clusters in one dimentional data

Tags: clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

I have a set of 1D data as shown below.
I want to find a metric that represents the number of clusters in data.
Is there any suitable metric that matches my criteria?

Example 1D data list:
[68, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 36, 33, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 35, 2, 3, 3]

If I plot this in a histogram plot with data on the X axis and frequency on the Y axis, I can see 3 clusters.
I wanted to check if an existing metric can return the number of clusters as 3 given the list of 1D data provided above.

PS: I can see that histogram binning works well in this case, as shown in the figure, please let me know if there are other standard metrics for this.

[image: Histogram plot of 1D data]

Comment: Take a look at the tags I have added - they should point you to relevant methods.

Comment: Inspect the 1D scatterplot, to start with. Small jittering can be added if there are many ties.